# exe file upload prevention

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

In my project i have created a file upload.Now it is required that any exe file or exe file in a zip folder having .zip as extension, be prevented from being uploaded.
Can someoe suggest me a solution?

Comment: So uploading .asp files is okay then?

Comment: You wish to look into the zip file and check for exe, is this correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [prevention of exe file upload in a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809242/prevention-of-exe-file-upload-in-a-website) (probably same user)

Comment: Btw, what for have you created a duplicated account http://stackoverflow.com/users/333371/niraj-choubey http://stackoverflow.com/users/312964/niraj-choubey ?

Answer (score 3):

For each of your task, you have to implement separate algorithm for check.

- Check extension before upload (see possible duplicate question)
- Check that uploaded zip is really an archive (mime type, libmagic, etc)
- Check that uploaded archive doesn't contain exe (unzip it, see previous paragraph)

Comment: +1 For libmagic suggestion. Its the brains behind the file() command.

Instead of enumerating badness, the OP should attempt to enumerate goodness instead.

Comment: @Niraj Choubey: See Robb's answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822521/exe-file-upload-prevention/2822560#2822560